# Слово "докука"

Tags: этимология, устаревшие-слова

Все никак не могу понять, является ли слово "докука" (от слова "докучать") устаревшим или нет? И, кстати, интересно бы узнать его этимологию.

Answer (score 3):

Да, во многих словарях к этому слову дается помета "устаревшее". 
Это слово исконно русское. Образовано от слова "кука" -  "печаль" ( родственные слова: скучать, кукситься).

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас слово "докука" употребляется в значении "забота, беспокойство, хлопоты", но первоначально оно имело другое значение: "неотступная, усиленная просьба, надоедание", от "кука" - "печаль". Родственные слова: скука, скучать, кукситься

Answer (score 1):

Да не назвал бы я его устаревшим... Скорее второе рождение переживает.

Comment: Согласна с Вами.